# classic asp delete rows and columns from an excel file

Tags: asp-classic, excel, vbscript, vba

how can I remove specific rows and columns from an excel file using only classic ASP? For example, given the excel file

```
col1  col2  col3
one   two   three
four  five  six
```

I want to be able to programmatically delete the first row and second column to produce

```
one   three
four  six
```

Thanks!

Comment: One more thing I should have mentioned -- the excel file are not necessarily in a nice tabular form (not necessarily headers followed by data), so for example there may be blank rows at the top of the file.

As far as I can tell, this precludes using the Jet OLE DB provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using an Excel.Application object.  For example:

```
dim oExcel, oWkBk  
set oExcel = CreateObject( "Excel.Application" )
oExcel.Visible = false
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = false
set oWkBk = oExcel.WorkBooks.Open( "C:\path\file.xls" )
```

You can then delete any individual cells with:

```
oExcel.Cells( 1, 1 ).Delete
```

Or entire rows/columns with:

```
oExcel.Cells(1,1).EntireColumn.Delete
oExcel.Cells(1,1).EntireRow.Delete
```

To check  if a cell is empty use:

```
if isEmpty(oExcel.Cells(1,1)) then ...
```

Finally, cleanup:

```
oWkBk.Close()
oExcel.Quit()
set oWkBk = nothing
set oExcel = nothing
```

For more info, try Googling things like "excel application object vbscript."  You can find many examples.  Unfortunately, I've found it impossible to find a complete reference.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and hopefully it'll work for what I'm doing.

I knew about the Excel.Application object, but too bad there's no complete reference online.

Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I was having permission problems creating Excel.Application...and then I found out our server doesn't have Excel! Anyway, thanks for the help...I'll have to use a workaround in the context of the larger problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually got the same problem--but have been avoiding addressing it.  If you find a way to avoid an Excel install on each server, I'd love to hear about it!